# spring-data-mongodb: how to find document by passing random attribute and its value

Tags: java, json, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have below document in my mongodb.

```
{
    "_id" : "840e922e-05e0-4e4d-b574-303a72425bdd",
    "_class" : "com.document.domain.Doc",
    "type" : "User",
    "name" : "steven",
    "index" : 0,
    "data" : "This is sample user",
    "properties" : {
        "displayName" : "steven",
        "lastName" : "smith"
    },
    "tags" : [ 
        "tag1", 
        "tag2"
    ],
    "categories" : [ 
        "category1", 
        "category2"
    ]
}
```

Now I want to retrieve document by passing any random attribute from above json.

```
Example: If I pass "type" as a key and "User" as value
         If I pass "name" as a key and "steven" as value
```

Like this key can be any random attribute from JSON and value will be its associates value, then it should return me that document.

I am trying below Query:

```
@Query("{'property':?0,'property':?1}")
List<Doc> findByKeyAndValue(String key, String value);
```

But no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean to say @Query("{'property':?1,'property':?0}")

Comment: You mean to say @Query("{'property':?1,'property':?0}")

Comment: Yeah that works. Thanks for the quick help. Can you answer the question so that I can accept it. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the **[placeholders](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.json-based)** that let you substitute the key and value from the method arguments into the JSON query string, where `?0` is the placeholder for the key and `?1` for the value. For example,

```
@Query("{?0:?1}")
List<Doc> findByKeyAndValue(String key, String value);
```